# Поиск по данным в Laravel

Tags: laravel, search

Есть блог на laravel, на главную страницу которого выводятся все записи. Также, на главной странице есть форма.

```
<form action="{{ route('search') }}" method="post">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="title" id="title" class="form-control" required>
      </div>
      <div class="fprm-group">
        <button type="submit" id="search" class="btn btn-primary">Найти</button>
      </div>
</form>
```

И роут

```
Route::any('/', 'IndexController@index')->name('search');
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как реализовать поиск по записям (постам) блога без ajax, и чтобы результат выгружался на эту же главную страницу? Т.е. в тот же роутер search.

Всем заранее большое спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

IndexController:

```
    public function index(SomeSearchModel $model, Request $request)
    {
        $searchResult = $model->search($request->post('title'));
        return view('youTemplateName', ['searchResult' => $searchResult]);
    }
```

Ваша форма:

```
    {{ @if(!empty($searchResult)) }}
       <!-- итерация по результатам -->
    {{ @endif }}
    <form action="{{ route('search') }}" method="post">
         <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" name="title" id="title" class="form-control" required>
         </div>
         <div class="fprm-group">
              <button type="submit" id="search" class="btn btn-primary">Найти</button>
         </div>
    </form>
```

Надеюсь все понятно

Comment: Ругается на метод post вот тут $searchResult = $model->search($request->post('title'));. Пишет: Method post does not exist.

Comment: Изменил в роуте метод any на метод post. Теперь пишет: MethodNotAllowedHttpException. Собственно, вопрос возник из-за того, что предложенный вами ответ вот тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/764459/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA-c-%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B2-laravel/764492?noredirect=1#comment1188462_764492 так и не взлетел..Пишет кучу ошибок, или просто не фильтрует данные...Решил разобраться на простом примере, пока начало аналогичное

Comment: @YuriGo в этом случае попробуйте $request->input('title') если в роутере хотите использовать any

Comment: Я уже по разному пробовал) Если меняю на input и any, вылетает: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::search()

Comment: @YuriGo все правильно =))) сначала нужно указать в какой модели вы ищете (откуда получаете данные)

Comment: В смысле вот тут public function index(SomeSearchModel $model, Request $request)? Если да, то я конечно же указываю свою модель

Comment: @YuriGo ок, а метод search в этой модели есть?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71394/discussion-between-yurigo-and-stereoflo).

Comment: Я думаю там должен быть не метод search а scopeSearch($query)

Comment: @Orange_shadow search это метод взятый из головы, который необходимо описать, чтобы им пользоваться.

Comment: @StereoFlo я просто подумал ты предыдущую запись смотрел, не суть, я вообще советую пользоваться для поиска каким нибудь спец средством, Algolia, Sphinx, ElasticSearch, етсь много готовых пакетов и туториолов  по настройке

Comment: @Orange_shadow это безусловно не предмет для спора, но все что ты перечислил это просто не реляционные хранилища, туда еще данные надо загрузить. В простом блоге - абсолютно бессмысленно